# Xcode 3.2 and iPhone OS 2.x frameworks

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am dealing with a project compiled for iPhone OS 2.0 on a previous version of Xcode.

I am using Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard and I know how to target for 2.0. The problem is that Xcode 3.2 do not comes with iPhone 2.0 frameworks.

How can I get these old frameworks and add to Xcode 3.2?

I cannot simply recompile to 2.2.1, or thousands of users who bought this application will be throwing flames at me, as the application always sold compatible with 2.0.

Any ideas? Can someone send me a link where I can download the frameworks for iPhone 2.0?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, but I discovered now that it IS possible to compile for 2.0 and 2.1 on Xcode 3.2. I have posted it on my blog on the following URL.
[Compiling for iPhone 2.0 and 2.1 on Xcode 3.2](http://www.eyeeffect.com/xcode3-2-iphoneos2/tips-tricks/2009/10/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard supports 2.2.1 only. You have to downgrade your developer machine if you want to support pre 2.2.1.

I doubt that there are many iPhone or iPod Touch users who did not even upgrade to 2.2.1. If you have any numbers on that matter, I'd be delighted if you would share them.

Comment: According to Admob, only 7% of the devices they serve ads to are running something older than 2.2.1: http://metrics.admob.com/2009/09/iphone-os-adoption/ Users of ad-supported application tend to lag users of paid applications in terms of OS upgrades, so I'd say that it's not worth worrying about pre-2.2.1 users.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/06/use-xcode-312-to-build-sdk-30-app-to-30.html) blog post might help you. You need to be ADC member though.